# android snackbar disappear when activity go to background

Tags: android, activity-lifecycle, android-snackbar

I show a snackbar on an event or when onViewAttachedToWindow is called and if a particular flag is set. Now if i start another activity without finish on current and then come back , the snackbar is no longer visible.
What could be happening

Activity A shows snackbar . Then starts B. A is in the activity stack . Now press back on B and A comes to top . This time snackbar is not visible. Is this expected behavior

Comment: please share your code

Comment: They automatically disappear after a timeout or after user interaction elsewhere on the screen, particularly after interactions that summon a new surface or activity. Snackbars can be swiped off screen.

Answer (score 0):

A Snackbar is literally attached to the view of an Activity, so the Activity owns it. If the Activity goes away, so does all its content (which includes the Snackbar).

This is not the same as Toasts, as they're owned by the entire Window, and the Window never goes away.

So in short, there is no way to "fix" your issue, as it isn't an actual issue. If you show a new activity, you'll have to show a new Snackbar if you want.

Comment: My issue is not that its not coming in the new activity. Activity A shows snackbar . Then starts B. A is in the activity stack . Now press back on B and A comes to top . This time snackbar is not visible. Is this expected behavior

Comment: Like Toast, Snackbar also visible for few seconds and later will get disappeared.

Comment: Not when u set Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE and i have set this

Comment: Saw in Android doc "They automatically disappear after a timeout or after user interaction elsewhere on the screen, particularly after interactions that summon a new surface or activity. Snackbars can be swiped off screen. " That explains it